# Getting a constructor error in apex class

Tags: apex

Below is my code for select option. I am getting an error like
Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption].Constructor(String)

Any idea?

```
String myContactId = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE id =:UserInfo.getUserId()].ContactId;



 List<npe5__Affiliation__c > SchoolList = [SELECT npe5__Organization__r.Name
             FROM npe5__Affiliation__c
                  WHERE npe5__Contact__c = :myContactId];




        for (npe5__Affiliation__c a : Schoollist) {

            SelectOption so = new SelectOption(a.npe5__Organization__r.Name);
                mySchools.add(so);
            }            
                              System.debug('SCHOOLS :'+myschools);
```

Comment: There is no method to define a selectoption with one parameter. Try `SelectOption so = new SelectOption(a.npe5__Organization__r.Name, a.npe5__Organization__r.Name);`

Comment: Is this still an outstanding question?

Answer (score 1):

`SelectOption` takes two arguments in its constructor: `value` and `label`. They are often the same:

```
new SelectOption(someName, someName)
```